# Android Facebook sign in error - 'remote_app_id does not match stored id'

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am getting very strange error while trying to sign in with the latest Facebook sdk:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
```

I have registered in facebook/developers, created app & assigned the app id & hask key properly.But still I'm getting this strange error.
I have gone through many posts in stackoverflow related with the same, but that's more related with iOS/Mac OS.
I am working with Android, so I don't have option to mention BundleId & all in gfacebook app settings.

Please some one suggest any solutions for this.

Comment: Hi,The issue got resolved by downloading the proper openSSL and then generating the keyhash as mentioned in the Facebook developer site.

Comment: which openSSL package was it?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue. In my case it was because I had left the app set to sandbox mode on Facebook, but was later logging in with a non-developer account for testing.